# c# Is there a parameters construct similar to multiple variable declaration?

Tags: c#

When declaring variables of the same type, we normally do this:

```
int a,b,c,d;
```

Is there a construct to do something similar with function parameters?
This function would take 3 integers:

```
void foo(int a,b,c)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such construct for declaring method arguments. You must declare your parameters one by one.

The closest thing that lets your method *receive* multiple parameters declared as a single array parameter is [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
void Foo(params int[] a) {
    ...
}
```

This method can be called as follows:

```
Foo(a, b, c, d);
```

The caller can pass any number of separate parameters, including zero. Your method would receive all of them in a single array.

Comment: Doesn't have a constraint that only three `int` parameters are allowed/possible. So you could call it `Foo(a, b, c, d, e);` without a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the case. I'm dealing with a function that takes  2 ints and 4 doubles. So it's ok to declare all the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not. This is the documentation about arguments:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691335(v=vs.71).aspx